# Determine own domain group memberships XP Professional

Tags: windows, user-accounts, windows-domain

This seems like it would be a simple question, but my Google skills have failed me.

When logged into a domain (as a domain user without any admin rights), how can I determine what groups my user account belongs to?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can also do it using the following:

```
gpresult
```

which will also show any GPO objects applied

Answer (score 13):

Ah - I managed to find a way to do this, from a command prompt:

```
net user {username} /domain
```

Which includes in its output a list of "global group memberships" corresponding to domain groups.

Comment: Very handy command.

Answer (score 2):

In more recent Windows versions you could use the [`whoami` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/whoami):

```
whoami /groups
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use (since I have Gnu32 grep):

```
gpresult /R | grep "following security groups" -A5000
```

This will perform a "list group policy" command for the current user, then pipe the output through grep so that only the information about group membership is written out.